# IE6 transparency Issues

Tags: css, filter, internet-explorer-6, opacity

I have been searching for answers for a couple of days and I found the answer awhile ago but it's not really what I want to get. The PNG backgrounds worked for IE8 and above. In IE6, it does not work. So I used this:

```
#nav_bar {
    *background:none; 
    *width: 34px; 
    *height: 151px;
    *filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=scale, src='../img/bg_navbar2.png');
```

I got a 100% transparent background but I want it only a 50% opacity. How do I tweak that line? Thanks for the help! I DON'T WANT TO USE JAVASCRIPT FOR THIS. I want a CSS3 semi-transparent background :)

IMAGES:
image in PS:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/431809_10200713326188890_673360556_n.jpg

actual background image in browsers [EXCEPT IE6]:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/575657_10200713331029011_963068431_n.jpg

Comment: people still use ie6?

Comment: You shouldn't use or support IE6.  There is **always** a better choice.  Using IE6, either personally or professionally, is unsafe and irresponsible. Don't take my word for it: http://browsehappy.com/ or straight from Microsoft: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @MonicaNegapatan Can we see your PNG?

Comment: @Passerby please refer to the edited post please, thanks.

Comment: @MonicaNegapatan No, I didn't mean the rendered outcome of the PNG; I meant the _actual_ PNG file. Because I happened to have an IE6 at hand right now :)

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/ioh80cwugm3s23r/bg_navbar.png

This is the actual file, it's semi-transparent in PS and also in browsers. @Passerby

Comment: @MonicaNegapatan Seems work for me: http://imgur.com/SZpsK7R

Comment: it's not working, still. I'm actually using IETester for it.

Comment: @MonicaNegapatan Mine is the actual IE in XP :) Anyway, if I remember correctly, IETester has the option to turn on/off filter.

Comment: @MonicaNegapatan Check the "Known Issue" on [this official page](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage): "CSS Filters are not working correctly in user mode : A solution is to launch IETester as admin user and CSS Filters will work."

Comment: I checked it, this is what was written: "Disable filters (transparency) feature on IE5.5/IE7/IE8". It didn't state IE6 and the checkbox is unchecked. @Passerby

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to add the Opacity. For example:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

I'd recommend using conditional HTML to call a stylesheet just for IE6. Stars are not to be trusted!